# Как узнать, какие файлы были использованы при рендере страницы в PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Я работаю с CMS Webasyst и бывает, что нужно узнать, какие php-файлы (контроллеры, классы...) были использованы при рендере шаблона. Какими способами в PhpStorm можно вывести список этих файлов?

Comment: Какую реальную цель вы преследуете?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) — функция возвращает список файлов, которые были загружены с помощью `include`, `include_once`, `require`, `require_once`.

Comment: Да, это именно то, что нужно. Но все же, в идеальном случае, хотелось бы, чтобы была функция в IDE, куда на вход подается лишь http-адрес, а на выходе мы получаем список файлов, участвующих в формировании страницы по введенному адресу. Есть что-нибудь подобное в современных IDE?

Comment: @qwoort Я не в курсе таких. И понятия не имею, зачем это вообще может быть нужно.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -r -A 20 -B 20 "имя_шаблона" папка_с_php_файлами
```

или

```
grep -rl "имя_шаблона" папка_с_php_файлами
```

если нужен только список файлов в которых встречается название шаблона.